# Python aggregate on a generator

Tags: python, lambda, generator

I have a generator that returns a list in each iteration. Each element of the list could be either 0 or 1. I want to count the total number of elements returned (including both 0 and 1) and the total number of 1 returned. I tried to implement this using reduce function like this :

```
t = reduce( (lambda x,y:(y[0]+1,y[1]+x)), gen_fn(), (0,0))
```

gen_fn() above is the generator that returns part of the list in each yield statement. I wanted to implement it by initializing with a tuple (0,0) for count. Given that the elements returned from generator are following :

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

My expected output for t is (5,3). But my code is failing with this error message :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Can anybody help me identify the problem? My lack of experience with reduce and lambda functions is preventing me from figuring out what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is your generator yielding a single value each pass, or a list of values? That is, is `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]` a single value (e.g. `next(gen_fn())`, or the whole set of values (e.g. from `list(gen_fn())`?

Comment: @Blckknght I'm wrong; `y` must be a list, not an integer, or the error message would be different. The error is for `y[1] + x`; `x` is the tuple, so `y` must be an indexable container of integers.

Comment: Although, given that; OP, why do you expect the output to be `(5, 3)`? Does `gen_fn()` only `yield` one value?

Comment: The funny thing is that I almost convinced @jonrsharpe that it returns list in the same time he almost convinced me that it returns integers. Seems like we have to wait for OP to clarify as one sentence negates another in his question.

Comment: *gen_fn() above is the generator that returns part of the list in each yield statement* implies to me that it's multiple lists, and the example is essentially just `[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]]` -> `(5,3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe has pointed out, you are using your `lambda` arguments backwards, given the way `reduce` works. However, there may be a further issue with how you're adding things up, if each item yielded from your generator is a list.

This issue is that your `y` value (the item yielded by the generator) is not a single number, but a list. You need to count its length and the number of `1`s it has, so you probably want your lambda function to be:

```
lambda x, y: (x[0]+len(y), x[1]+sum(y))
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the best answer here is to keep it simple:

```
count = 0
total = 0
for item in gen_fn():
    count += 1
    total += item
```

Using `reduce()` here only makes your code less readable.

If your question is code golf and you want a one liner (while keeping lazy evaluation), then you want:

```
count, total = collections.deque(zip(itertools.count(1), itertools.accumulate(gen_fn())), maxlen=1).pop()
```

Of course, you'd be mad to pick such a construction over the simple solution.

Edit:

If the generator yields multiple smaller parts, then simply use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(gen_fn())` to flatten it.

Comment: I'd upvote multiple times if I could.  I can see what this code is doing immediately; there's no reason to obfuscate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `lambda` arguments the wrong way around; the first argument (`x`) is the total so far (the tuple) and the second (`y`) is the new value (the integer). Try:

```
t = reduce((lambda x, y: (x[0]+1, x[1]+y)), gen_fn(), (0,0))
```

Using a dummy function:

```
def gen_fn():
    for x in [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]:
        yield x
```

I get `(5, 3)`.

This equivalent implementation of `reduce` from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) might make things clearer:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        try:
            initializer = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise TypeError('reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value')
    accum_value = initializer
    for x in it:
        accum_value = function(accum_value, x) # note value so far is first arg
    return accum_value
```

Answer (score 0):

How about taking a completely different approach?

```
t = [(len(row), len(filter(lambda x: x == 1, row))) for row in gen_fn()]
```

Comment: I don't think `gen_fn` is yielding lists; see the dummy implementation in my answer

Comment: "I have a generator that returns a list in each iteration." I'm confused now. "gen_fn() above is the generator that returns part of the list." What's part of the list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I think the yielded values must be lists, or the original code would be giving an error about trying to index `y`, which is not subscriptable.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, spot on; I just commented as much above!